# Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled in spring-boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I do not have any code yet, I just want to configure the project

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
              SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
    }

}
```

My `pom.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.uz.shop</groupId>
    <artifactId>shop-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>shopspring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.uz.shop.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

this my results

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-15 21:22:36.175 ERROR 7836 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ClassLoaderDelegate
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
```

Comment: ```spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/milk?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true    
hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
```

Comment: Can you please share the entire stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your stacktrace shows the error is due to am missing  `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException` . This usually happens when you use a java version higher than java 8 along with spring-boot-starter-jpa . In your case the stacktrace you have attached is only partial and i could make out only this much detail about the issue. Pleas share the entire stacktrace if this is not working for you.
Try adding the following dependency in your pom :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```